# Top N results in BigQuery across multiple columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot, pivot-table

Let's say I have records as follows:

```
id   studio        movie
1    fox           avatar
2    paramount     transformers
etc.
```

And I want to get a query of the top 2 studios by number of titles and within that, the first 3 movies, sorted alphabetically. The results would look something like this:

```
studio (top 2 by title cnt)        title (top 3 alphabetically)
fox                                avatar
fox                                avatar2
fox                                avatar3
sony                               ace in the hole
sony                               antonio
sony                               spider-man
```

How would I do a query to get this? So far I have something like this, but I'm not sure how to do the sort at the end:

```
select * from `table` where studio in (
    SELECT studio FROM `table` group by studio order by count(*) desc limit 3
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to use some combination of window functions (like `ROW_NUMBER`) and aggregation.

Here is one possible approach (I made up the table identifiers, so you'll have to insert your own):

```sql
WITH studio_counts AS
    (

        SELECT
            studio
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY COUNT(studio) DESC) As rownum
        FROM
            project.dataset.movies
        GROUP BY
            studio
    )

SELECT
    mc.studio
    ,mc.movie_title
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            m.studio
            ,m.movie_title
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY m.studio ORDER BY m.movie_title) AS rownum2
        FROM
            studio_counts AS sc

            INNER JOIN project.dataset.movies AS m
            ON sc.studio = m.studio
        WHERE
            sc.rownum < 3
    ) AS mc
WHERE
    mc.rownum2 < 4
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer, I was able to use something similar for my needs. For doing 3 levels of aggregation, would 2 `with` statements be used? or how would the complexity of the above query change?

Comment: thanks, just posted a follow-up question here with a bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT studio, title
FROM (
  SELECT studio, ARRAY_AGG(movie ORDER BY movie LIMIT 3) movies
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY studio
  ORDER BY COUNT(movie) DESC
  LIMIT 2
), UNNEST(movies) title
```