# Generalizing Top N query in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot, pivot-table

This is a follow-up question to generalize the case for [Top N results in BigQuery across multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56194742/top-n-results-in-bigquery-across-multiple-columns). Let us now take the following data:

```
 year   genre         studio            title       revenue
2014    fantasy       fox               avatar      10
2015    fantasy       fox               avatar      12
2016    fantasy       fox               avatar      12
2015    action        sony              spider-man  10
2015    romance       paramount         love letter 15
2015    action        sony              spider-man  10
2015    action        sony              spider-man  10
2015    action        disney            toy story   10
2015    action        sony              edgar       4
2015    action        sony              thomas      1
2015    fantasy       fox               avatar      2
```

I would like to get the following results to build a tree structure:

```
Past 2 years, Top 2 genres (Alphabetically), Top 2 studios (by Count), Top 2 titles by SUM Revenue DESC
```

And so we'd get something like:

[image]

The query that I'm looking to achieve, conceptually, is something like this:

```
SELECT year, genre, studio, title, SUM(revenue)
FROM titles
GROUP BY year, genre, studio, title

// in pseudocode
ORDER BY
    (year DESC) LIMIT 2,
    (genre ASC) LIMIT 10,
    (COUNT(studio) DESC) LIMIT 2,
    (SUM(revenue) DESC) LIMIT 2
```

What would be the best approach to doing the above, which would be more of a generalization of building a tree structure in BQ.

Comment: You've got few answers already on your initial question! Have you tried something to generalize by yourself? You should show some efforts, otherwise it looks like you are just outsourcing your tasks

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I've added a bounty here. I've been doing this with your approach, using `array_agg` but I think perhaps the other approach would be more generalized to work with various sorts/levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to find 'avatar2' in your dataset, but it is there in the result. So, I couldn't verify the answer to the edge.This is the SQL Server query which I came up with. I hope there won't be many changes required.

```
 WITH A as 
    (SELECT 
    year, 
    genre, 
    studio,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY year, genre, studio) AS studio_movie_count,
    title,
    revenue,
    SUM(revenue) OVER (PARTITION BY year, genre, studio,title) AS revenue_sum FROM movies),

    B as

    (SELECT 
    year,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY year DESC) AS year_num, 
    genre,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY year ORDER BY genre ASC) AS genre_num,
    studio,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY year, genre ORDER BY studio_movie_count DESC) AS studio_num,
    title,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY year, genre, studio ORDER BY revenue_sum DESC) AS title_num,
    revenue

    FROM A)

    SELECT year, genre, studio, title, revenue
    FROM B
    WHERE year_num < 3 AND
    genre_num < 3 AND
    studio_num < 3 AND
    title_num < 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter the rows for top 2 years in subquery while also finding the movie count by studio and revenue sum by title.

Then find rank by genre, studio, revenue and filter for top 2.

```
select year, genre, studio, title, revenue 
from (
    select year, genre, studio, title, revenue,
        dense_rank() over (partition by year order by genre) as genre_rank,
        dense_rank() over (partition by year, genre order by count_by_studio desc) as studio_rank,
        dense_rank() over (partition by year, genre, studio order by revenue_by_title desc) as title_rank
    from (
        select year,
            genre,
            studio,
            title,
            revenue,
            dense_rank() over (order by year desc) as year_rank,
            count(*) over (partition by year, genre, studio) as count_by_studio,
            sum(revenue) over (partition by year, genre, studio, title) as revenue_by_title
        from titles
    ) where year_rank <= 2
) where genre_rank <= 2
and studio_rank <= 2
and title_rank <= 2;
```